# How to find first-order quasi-linear PDEs form second-order quasi-linear PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Transform $u_{tt} u_{xx}-u^{2}_{tx} + uu_{tt} + 1=0 $ into first-order quasi-linear PDEs.

**Attempt:**

$u_{tt}(u_{xx}+u)=(u_{tx}-1)(u_{tx}+1)$

To get

1. $u_{tt} = u_{tx}-1\Rightarrow u_t = u_x +F(t)$, by integral respect to t.($F(t)=\int (-1)dt$)
2. $u_{xx}+u = u_{tx}+1 \Rightarrow u_x +G(u,t,x)=u_t$, by integral respect to x.($G(u,t,x)=\int (u-1) dx$)

Or

1.$u_{tt} = u_{tx}+1\Rightarrow u_t = u_x +F(t)$, by integral respect to t.($F(t)=\int 1dt$)

2.$u_{xx}+u = u_{tx}-1 \Rightarrow u_x +G(u,t,x)=u_t$, by integral respect to x.($G(u,t,x)=\int (u+1) dx$)

$ \ $

I think that I am wrong. Can anyone give me some hints?